# Make scroll bar unvisible, but still being able to scroll within a Bootstrap grid

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I found this popular [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16671476/4314952) (see also [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5GCsJ/954/)), which covers exactly my problem. But after applying this solution to my MWE, see on [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/r6Y2Bokl5z), it still doesn't work. Why is it not working?

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
 <h1>Hello!</h1>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3" style="background-color:yellow;">
        <div class="outer">
            <div class="inner">
                <p>hello</p>
                <br>
                ...
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-9" style="background-color:pink;">
        <p>hello once</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.inner {
  height:200px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.outer{
  overflow:hidden; 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the effect within a bootstrap column, you can set the right margins to a minus value and thereby hide the scrollbar.
Also, add some more content so you've got something to scroll!

```css
.inner {
  height:200px;
  overflow-y: auto;
margin-right:-15px;
}

.outer{
  overflow:hidden; 
  margin-right:-15px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 
   <div class="container">
 <h1>Hello!</h1>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3" style="background-color:yellow;">
        <div class="outer">
            <div class="inner">
                <p>hello</p>
                <br>
                ...
    <p>hello</p>
                <br>
                ...
                <p>hello</p>
                <br>
                ...
 <br>
                ...
                <p>hello</p>
                <br>
                ...
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-9" style="background-color:pink;">
        <p>hello once</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can I be sure, that the scrollbar has always a width of 15px?

Comment: Have a look at this link:  http://www.textfixer.com/tutorials/browser-scrollbar-width.php which seems to suggest that 17px is about standard. However, if you want to be exact, you could calculate the width via javascript.